# Running of selenium script is not consistant

Tags: html, selenium

I wrote a selenium script to automate some of the manual check on http:obsessory.com
It consist of looping concept 
Example : mouse hover on Top menu and click on various sub menus.When I am running my script sometime it is working fine some time it is giving "Nosuchelement Exception".I have used Thread.sleep everywhere it needs.

If you go through website you will get to know under "Women" top menu there are 20+ sub menus.So when I start running my script some time it is running till 2nd sub menu sometime 7th sub menu. I don't understand why this is happening

If you want anything you can ask. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Monil, Share me your Code.This is Sync Error. Thread.sleep is not a good option. We should use implicit wait for it.

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator); Use this. It will help you.. If you have more query. please share your code..

Comment: can you please share the html code for your menus & submenus? You most probably will have the best shot with using waits for certain elements to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

instead of using Thread.sleep can you use

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

this will wait for element for 100 seconds before returning /Nosuchelement Exception' if selenium found element before specified time it will return and doesn't use 100 sec every time you find element.

let me know if this worked!!